# Getting this error: Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1

Tags: google-apps-script, range

I have been using a code for some time and a couple of days ago it started giving the following error:

This is the code:

```
    function copy_end(){
  var pedidos = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('pedidos');
  var packing_list = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('PACKING LIST');
  var getRange = pedidos.getRange(13,19,pedidos.getRange("T10").getValue(),16);
  var DataCopied = getRange.getValues();

  // I defined the variables for better understanding      
  var startRow = packing_list.getLastRow()+1; // +1 because remember that while a range index starts at 1, 1, the JavaScript array will be indexed from [0][0].
  var startColumn = 1;
  var numRows = DataCopied.length;
  var numColumns = DataCopied[0].length;
  packing_list.getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows, numColumns).setValues(DataCopied);
};
```

The error is in line 4, which is the variable getRange, and the range from the sheet that it is referring to is the following:
[image: sheet]
The number of rows in the range is bigger than one, it is in fact 4. Does anybody know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that sh1.getRange("T10").getValue() was zero

```
function copy_end(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('pedidos');
  var psh = ss.getSheetByName('PACKING LIST');
  var rg1 = sh1.getRange(13,19,sh1.getRange("T10").getValue(),16);
  var vs1 = rg1.getValues();
  psh.getRange(prsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs1.length, vs1[0].length).setValues(vs1);
};
```

Comment: I tried this and I still got the same error :( The weird thing is that the error only occurs sometimes and if i come back hours later and try again it works again for a couple of times and then after i have run it 2-3 times it stops working again.